# How to edit file name and file directory in save file dialog (windows forms)?

Tags: c#, winforms, user32

I tried to do but not work. I would like to control save file dialog from active window for edit filename, file path and press save button. currently, I success only press save button.
Does anyone can help?

```
public void YourMethod()
    {
        IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();
        var name = GetActiveWindowTitle(handle);    

        if (handle != IntPtr.Zero && name == "Save As")
        {
            // Do your work here
            label1.Text = name;
            EditFileLoMethod(handle);
            EditFileNameMethod(handle);
        }
       
    }

    
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam);
    public void EditFileLoMethod(IntPtr handle)
    {
       
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindowEx(handle, IntPtr.Zero, "ReBarWindow32", null);
        SendMessage(hWnd, (int)0x000C, IntPtr.Zero,@"D:\");

    }
    public void EditFileNameMethod(IntPtr handle)
    {
        
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindowEx(handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
        SendMessage(hWnd, (int)0x000C, IntPtr.Zero, "Test.xlsx");

    }
```

Comment: so you want to automate another process's ui? why not use some existing tools/frameworks?

Comment: @LeiYang which tool/frameworks? would you please recommend me?

Comment: [UI Automation Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview)